# Elasticsearch - Sum with group by

Tags: elasticsearch

I couldn't apply the concept of chain aggregation... i need help with this scenario:
My documents look like this:

```
{
  "date":"2019-01-30",
  "value":1234.56,
  "partnerId":9876
}
```

and i would like to filter by date (month) and summarize them by partner Id, and then count it, obtaining a result like:

```
{
   "partnerId": 9876,
   "totalValue": 12345567.87,
   "count": 6574
}
```

How would this query look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by sub aggregation, in other words aggregation inside aggregation.

For your case first you want to group by `parternId`, so you will require [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on `parternId` field. Lets call this aggregation as `partners`. This will give you two values of your expected result, `parternId` and `count`.

Now for each of the groups (bucket) of `partnerId`, `totalValue` is required i.e. sum of `value` for each partnerId. This can be done by adding [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) inside term aggregation `partners`. So the final query along with the filter for date (month) will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "date": {
            "gte": "2019-01-01",
            "lte": "2019-01-31"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "partner": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "partnerId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "totalValue": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Sample Result (agg only):

```
"aggregations": {
    "partner": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 9876,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "totalValue": {
            "value": 3704.68017578125
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 9878,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "totalValue": {
            "value": 2454.1201171875
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

In the result above `key` is `partnerId`, `doc_count` is `count` and `totalValue.value` is `totalValue` of your expected result.

Comment: hey tks! that pretty much solved it! quick question though: the results is bringing "Hits", which are quite lengthy... is there a way to not fetch them, and bring only the "aggregations"?

Comment: Yes after aggs block add `"size": 0`